# Handle Send Parse PushNotification errors/timeout

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Is there a way to set a timeout or to get an error for the cases we try to send a push notification from a device that is disconnected from the network???

I've looked all over on the documentation of the API and I have also googled about this but I could not find anything on how to accomplish this.

For example, given the code below, how can we handle the case that the push notification was not sent because, at that moment, the device had no network connectivity?? (Instead this piece of code just fails silently wether I pass a callback to sendInBackground or not, the ParseException param is always null...)

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setMessage("Test...");
push.setQuery(someParseQuery);
push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback(){
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e == null){
            //it always gets here, even if device has no connectivity...
        } else {
            //never enters here when there is no network connectivity...
        }                    
    }
});
```

Would be much appreciated for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr

SendCallBack doesnt raise a ParseException when no internet is present, thus making it impossible to check if a push has actually been send or not. A workaround would be to write a wrapper or some kind that would check if an internet connection is present and then send the push, but such a solution would be far from ideal.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Can't you give

```
push.sendInBackground();
```

a handler to handle the return of the push?

> **[sendInBackground](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/)**
>
> ```
> public void sendInBackground(SendCallback callback)
>
> Sends this push notification in a background thread. 
> This is preferable to using send(), unless your code is already running from a background thread.
>
> Parameters:
> callback - callback.done(e) is called when the send completes.
> ```

Example code:

```
push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback(){
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e == null){
            //Succesfully send your pushnotification
        } else {
            //Oh uh, something went wrong :(
        }                    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bart, but passing a handler to the sendInBackground doesnt work because the ParseException is always null (i.e., "successfull") even when the push notification is sent without network connectivity...

Comment: Hmm that's a shame, I expected it to throw an expection since the ParseException has an enum CONNECTION_FAILED, for when connections to the Parseservers fail.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for that, but I have just tested it several times and I confirmed that the exception is always null... But maybe I am doing something terribly wrong... Did it work for you?

Comment: No, I havnt ran in the problem of testing it yet without internet connection but I am afraid I'll run into the same thing. It depends per callBack what kind of exceptions it can raise and sadly the exceptions that my SaveCallback raise arnt being raised by the SendCallback

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant or not, but you have enabled the setting that allow clients to push notifications? 'By default clients are not allowed to push notification.'

Comment: It could have been because of that, but, indeed I have it enabled

Comment: You got me stumbled here, I've been looking around as well to see if I could perhaps find anything related to sending pushes when no internet connection is present and it seems it's completely empty of any kind of problems. One quickfix could be that you before you send make your own background thread that will check until internet connection is available and will send it then. But personally I'd try and ask on the Parse.com forums, since it looks like people who are involved in the development of Parse comment there as well from time to time. I'm sorry I can't be of more help!